# How to use a template class C++

Tags: c++, class, templates

I'm having a problem using a class I wrote in C++. I've just recently set out on learning C++ and I quickly searched for the proper way but after putting it in the "proper" way I still got an error....So I apologize in advance if this is just some stupid misunderstanding (although I doubt it...) the relevant code is below

ArrayList.h

```
#ifndef ARRAYLIST_H_
#define ARRAYLIST_H_

#include <string>

template<class T>
class ArrayList {

    private:
         //Data fields-------------------//
        T *array;
        int size;
        int capacity;
        bool sorted;

        //Methods-----------------------//
        void reallocate();
        void reallocate(int newSize);

        T* mergeSort(T* array, int arraySize);

    public:
        //Constructors------------------//
        ArrayList();
        ArrayList(int theSize);

        //Methods-----------------------//
        //Operations
        bool add(T element);
        bool add(T element, int index);
        bool add(ArrayList<T> list);
        bool add(ArrayList<T> list, int index);
        std:string toString();
};

#endif /* ARRAYLIST_H_ */
```

ArrayList.cpp

```
#include "ArrayList.h"

//~Constructors-----------------------------------------------
/**
 * Default constructor,
 * creates a 20 element ArrayList, of type T.
 */
template<class T>
ArrayList<T>::ArrayList() {

    array = new T[20];
    capacity = 20;
    size = 0;
}

//~Methods---------------------------------------------------
/**
 * Adds the passed in element to the end of the ArrayList.
 *
 * Runs in O(n) in worst case, where reallocate is called.
 *
 * @param element the element to add to the array.
 */
template<class T>
bool ArrayList<T>::add(T element) {

    bool value = false;

    if (element != NULL) {
        if ((size - 1) == capacity) {

            value = reallocate();
        }

        if (value) {
            array[size] = element;
            size++;
        }
    }

    return value;
}
```

ArrayListTest.cpp

```
#include "ArrayList.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {

    using namespace std;

    ArrayList<int> myList();

    myList.add(184387);
    myList.add(14);
    myList.add(147);
    myList.add(1);
    myList.add(-37);
    myList.add(584);
    myList.add(-2147);
    myList.add(0);
    myList.add(-75);
    myList.add(147);
    myList.add(-37);
    myList.add(0);
    myList.add(25);
    myList.add(187);
    myList.add(92);
    myList.add(-17);

    cout << myList.toString();
}
```

The errors occur in the TestArrayList.cpp file. I have an error on all of the add calls and on the cout call.

The error on the add calls is:

```
request for member 'add' in 'myList', which is of non-class type 'ArrayList<int>()'
```

The error on the cout call is:

```
Method 'toString' could not be resolved
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Note, there is standart class  with similar functionality: `std::vector<T>`

Comment: yeah I know, I was just writing this to get a feel for C++ and hone my skills....a LinkedList is next

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ArrayList<int> myList();
```

should be

```
ArrayList<int> myList;
```

You're running into **most vexing parse** (google it). Basically, `ArrayList<int> myList();` doesn't declare a variable, but declares a function called `myList` that takes no arguments and returns an `ArrayList<int>`.

Some side notes:

- you're allocating memory in the constructor, but never freeing it. You should have a destructor.
- that means you should obey the rule of three (google it)
- **my psyching abilities** (yes, I have them, keep it on the down low) tell me that your next problem is going to be that it's not linking. **Move the implementations to the header**. Templates must have the implementation visible to all translation units that specialize them.

Comment: ...and then throw away all of the above and use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: yes Jerry I am aware that vector does all of that, I'm not writing this out of utility

Comment: That did it! Thanks a lot Luchian! So should the implementation ALWAYS be in the header? Or is it for all templates? Or is it because of something special I did?

Comment: @Ethan Because it is a template it needs to be in the header because the compiler must have direct access to the code wherever it is used.

Comment: Thanks Ben! I was getting really confused over that because in C++ Primer Plus (in the class section, I haven't found the template section) they always split the class into a header file with prototypes and a cpp file with function declarations. Thanks again!